# mysql select date using timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

in my database i use a column named `startdate` and in the column there are rows with timestamps, looking like: `1410178260`

Normally, when i use a datetime field and i want to select all the items with the date of today, i run this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM agenda2 WHERE DATE(startdate) >= CURRENT_DATE()";
```

But now, using the timestamps, i don't know how to make a query that selects all the items inserted today.
Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to date using the function from_unixtime()

```
mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME('1410178260');
+-----------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME('1410178260') |
+-----------------------------+
| 2014-09-08 17:41:00         |
+-----------------------------+
```

So you may do as

```
SELECT id FROM agenda2 WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(startdate)) >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: A [*Sargable query*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) will be `SELECT id FROM agenda2 WHERE startdate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE())`

Comment: Yes Sargable query will  make it better in terms of performance when the index is involved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using unix timestamps then you've got to use

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM agenda2 WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(startdate)) >= CURRENT_DATE()";
```

Consider that both versions can't make use of an index.

see [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)